# FlatList converting single item to an array

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app I'm fetching my data with axios. As we know, we can not render data in FlatList as an object it must be an array. When I fetch my data from server if it is single item it is object, if it is more than one it returns me as an array. How can I show my single item in flatlist?

state:

```
state = {
    events: [],
    isLoading: true,
    errorCode: null,
    errorMessage: null,
}
```

my flatlist instance;

```
let events = <FlatList
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        data={this.state.events}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={this.dataEmpty}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <EventsList
                startDate={item.startDate}
                headLine={item.eventName}
                description={item.location}
                endDate = {item.endDate}
            />;
        }}
    />;
```

Comment: paste your response in question

Comment: if you get an object from the API, convert it to array of single item

Comment: Use `Array.isArray(<response>)` to check if it's an array or not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: how are you assigning api res to event state ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure that the data is an array **before** you store it into state, if not change it into an array. 
`Array.isArray()` is the correct way to check if something is an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

It is possible to create a simple function

1. check for an array,
2. if it is an array return it,
3. if it isn't an array convert it into an array, and return it

```js
let result1 = {id: 1};          // object result
let result2 = [{id:1}, {id: 2}] // array result

function checkData (result) {
  if (Array.isArray(result)) {
    return result
  } else {
    return [result]
  }
}

console.log(checkData(result1))
console.log(checkData(result2))
```

I think doing it after you have already got it into state  isn't the best way. So you will probably want to do something like this in your `axios` call before you use `setState`

Comment: I'm trying your solution. I will inform you later. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes it did the trick. As your response I handled it in my axios state. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if events is not an array return it in an array:

```
.... 
      data={Array.isArray(this.state.events)
         ? this.state.events
         : [this.state.events]}
....
```

Comment: it throws me objects are not valid as react child (found: object with keys {}) . If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Yes with this version your code works too. Thanks for response.